# Why I can't get this jquery code to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the page scroll to post which has specific id e.g. post-21 post-22 etc

But It won't work. what could be wrong with my syntax here please?

```
// this is number of posts visible. returns e.g. 2
var posts_visible = <?php echo $news['num_per_page']; ?>;
// this is number of more posts loaded. returns e.g. 2
var posts_more = <?php echo $news['num_per_more']; ?>;
// here i calculate the value to know which position should we be at after scroll
var newposition = posts_visible + (posts_more * $.cookie('n_more'));
// here i am trying to set #post-(thepostnumber)
var thispost = '$("#post-' + newposition + '")';
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: thispost.position().top + 'px',
    scrollLeft: thispost.position().left + 'px'
},1000);
```

Please note that `alert(thispost)` returns accurately the post with the proper ID i should be at. Just can't get it to work in the animate/scroll. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just the selector as a string, not the entire `$()` function call, like this:

```
var thispost = $("#post-" + newposition).position();
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: thispost.top + 'px',
    scrollLeft: thispost.left + 'px'
},1000);
```

Also it can be optimized like above...no need to call [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) twice to get the same result.

Comment: @Ahmad - that's the correct alert, it *is* an object.  If you want something meaningful, do `alert(thispost.top)` with my code above.

Comment: I think i found my mistake I will post it a more appropriate question.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var thispost = $("#post-" + newposition);
```

You don't want to create a string "`$("#post-42")`", you want to create the string "`#post-42`" and pass it to the `$` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var thispost = $("#post-"+ newposition);
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: thispost.position().top + 'px',
    scrollLeft: thispost.position().left + 'px'
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but worth sharing. I use this plugin when I want to scroll something http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/